# Can I specify different set of upstream directives for different routes in Amazon ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, amazon-elb

I am currently using Nginx server for my load balancer. But in order to use the Amazon's Load balancing feature I want to move to Amazon ELB. But the problem is my application has different routes or locations (same domain name with different sub-urls) that are handled by different ec2 instances. Like for example. (abc.com/ is handled by a set of ec2 instances while abc.com/xyz/* is handled by another set of instances). For now I use nginx to specify different upstream lists and and locations they handle. I tried to look at that in Amazon ELB but I didn't find it. So is it possible to do that in Amazon ELB or is there any way around that?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry - other than supporting sticky sessions, there is no request-based routing logic in ELB.